# Object Oriented Graph Hierarchy with Depth First Search revisited

Tags: c++

This question is follow up to [Object Oriented Graph Hierarchy with Depth First Search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116813/object-oriented-graph-hierarchy-with-depth-first-search). I tried to fulfill every point which @LokiAstari mentioned. I think I succeeded in everything except Visitor Pattern.

I came to implementation of a function `void BiGraph::addAdjacentImpl(int fVertex, int sVertex)` in different way. Now it will do very heavy checks. Hope I didn't miss something. Also, I implemented check for keeping being a tree with ad-hoc approach (not sure about it). Every time edge is to be added, it is added only one way, and then `traverse` is called to check if cycle will be created or not, so it is kind of online check. Could you please pay extra attention to this function and criticize it as much as possible, because it is very essential part.

**Graph.cpp** is the outcome of complains of linker. Seems like inlining of `print` function call made the complains. The file implements only `operator<<`s, so if clients write their own non-virtual functions I think it doesn't violate ODR which is ok, I hope I'm not missing anything.
Also I made heavy unit test, but it is just a bunch of try catch statements, everything was executed in a way it was waited to.

**Graph.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Graph
{
public:
    void addAdjacent(int fVertex, int sVertex) { addAdjacentImpl(fVertex, sVertex); }
    const std::vector<char>  areConnected(int sourceVertex) const { return areConnectedImpl(sourceVertex); }
    void print(std::ostream& os) const { printImpl(os); }
private:
    virtual void printImpl(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    virtual void addAdjacentImpl(int fvertex, int svertex) = 0;
    virtual const std::vector<char> areConnectedImpl(int sourcevertex) const = 0;
    virtual void traverse(int sourcevVertex, std::vector<char>& areVisited) const = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Graph* g);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::unique_ptr<Graph>& g);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<Graph>& g);
#endif
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
#include "graph.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Graph* g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::unique_ptr<Graph>& g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<Graph>& g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}
```

**BiGraph.h**

```
#ifndef BIGRAPH_H
#define BIGRAPH_H

#include "graph.h"
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class BiGraph :public Graph
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > graph;
    int maxVertexCount;
    std::string name;
public:
    BiGraph(int maxVertexCount_, std::string name_);

private:
    virtual void printImpl(std::ostream& os) const override;
    virtual void addAdjacentImpl(int fVertex, int sVertex) override;
    virtual const std::vector<char> areConnectedImpl(int sourcevertex) const override;
    virtual void traverse(int sourceVertex, std::vector<char>& areVisited) const override;
};

#endif
```

**BiGraph.cpp**

```
#include "BiGraph.h"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

BiGraph::BiGraph(int maxvertexcount_, std::string name_):
    graph(maxvertexcount_), 
    maxVertexCount(maxvertexcount_), 
    name(name_)
{

}

void BiGraph::addAdjacentImpl(int fVertex, int sVertex)
{
    if (fVertex == sVertex)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(name + ": Trying to add a loop");
    }

    if (fVertex <0 || fVertex > maxVertexCount)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range(name + ": trying to add non-existent vertex");
    }
    if (sVertex < 0 || sVertex > maxVertexCount)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range(name + ": trying to add non-existent vertex");
    }

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit;
    cit = std::find(graph[fVertex].cbegin(), graph[fVertex].cend(), sVertex);
    if (cit != graph[fVertex].cend())
    {
        throw std::logic_error(name + ": Connecting these vertices will make the graph no longer tree");
    }

    cit = std::find(graph[sVertex].cbegin(), graph[sVertex].cend(), fVertex);
    if (cit != graph[sVertex].cend())
    {
        throw std::logic_error(name + ": Connecting these vertices will make the graph no longer tree");
    }

    graph[fVertex].push_back(sVertex);

    std::vector<char> areVisited(maxVertexCount, false);

    traverse(sVertex, areVisited);

    if (areVisited[fVertex])
    {
        graph[fVertex].pop_back();
        throw std::logic_error(name + ": Connecting these vertices will cause a cycle");
    }

    graph[sVertex].push_back(fVertex);

}

void BiGraph::traverse(int sourceVertex, std::vector<char>& areVisited) const
{
    if (areVisited[sourceVertex])
        return;
    areVisited[sourceVertex] = true;
    for (auto& x:graph[sourceVertex])
    {
        traverse(x, areVisited);
    }
}

const std::vector<char> BiGraph::areConnectedImpl(int sourceVertex) const
{
    std::vector<char> areVisited(maxVertexCount, false);
    traverse(sourceVertex, areVisited);
    return areVisited;
}

void BiGraph::printImpl(std::ostream& os) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
    {
        os << i << ": ";
        for (auto& j:graph[i])
        {
            os << j << ' ';
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**GraphFactory.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPHFACTORY_H
#define GRAPHFACTORY_H
#include "graph.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class GraphFactory
{
public:
    GraphFactory()=default;

    std::unique_ptr<Graph> getBiGraph(int size, std::string name);

    ~GraphFactory()=default;
};

#endif
```

**GraphFactory.cpp**

```
#include "GraphFactory.h"
#include "BiGraph.h"

std::unique_ptr<Graph> GraphFactory::getBiGraph(int size, std::string name)
{
    return std::make_unique<BiGraph>(size, name);
}
```

Comment: Just found what is the difference. I don't know, in real the project I started was just to learn to hide implementation and reduce compilation dependencies. I read effective c++ by Scott Meyers, 3rd edition, and wanted to apply some exception catching. That is my first try to create something really big. I might add trees to hierarchy, but the intention is not to accomplish the DFS in all contexts, but just to have a readable code with no bugs. I would like to add Directional Graph, which is, if I recall it correctly, is closer to tree. I might try to add some type traits as well.

Answer (score 3):

I will review your code independently; if you get conflicting recommendations from other reviews, use your judgement to reconcile them.

### It's OK to have virtual functions in the public interface.

```cpp
class Graph
{
public:
    void addAdjacent(int fVertex, int sVertex) { addAdjacentImpl(fVertex, sVertex); }
    const std::vector<char>  areConnected(int sourceVertex) const { return areConnectedImpl(sourceVertex); }
    void print(std::ostream& os) const { printImpl(os); }
};
```

This code has no purpose: you are not adding any context and they just add
unnecessary indirection. The optimizer will probably optimize it away,
but I see no sense in having this code.

### Pointers in stream operators are not the best idea.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Graph* g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::unique_ptr<Graph>& g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<Graph>& g)
{
    g->print(os);
    return os;
}
```

You probably should just use constant references instead of pointers. This is
the canonical stream operator and adding pointers is just a special case. You
can always dereference the pointer in the calling code (unless you intend to
print the pointer address too).

If you are passing in pointers, you should probably check whether the pointers are
not null. This can either be an `assert` or a throw `std::invalid_argument`.

### Override is sufficient.

```cpp
class BiGraph
{
  virtual void printImpl(std::ostream& os) const override;
}
```

Just use `override`, since `virtual` is implied here. As a rule of thumb use `virtual`
at the base to indicate a virtual function and use `override` on the derived functions.

### Prefer assert to handle programming mistakes.

```cpp
void BiGraph::addAdjacentImpl(int fVertex, int sVertex)
{
    if (fVertex == sVertex)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(name + ": Trying to add a loop");
    }

    if (fVertex <0 || fVertex > maxVertexCount)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range(name + ": trying to add non-existent vertex");
    }
    if (sVertex < 0 || sVertex > maxVertexCount)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range(name + ": trying to add non-existent vertex");
    }
}
```

All things that can be considered "programming" mistakes should be checked against
with asserts. The problem is, if this is a programming mistake, what can the calling
code do about it? If this is some source of input, that input should have been validated
at a higher level.

If the `(fVertex == sVertex)` is within the realm of normal operations, it
probably should a different exception than `logic_error`.

### Use `bool` for boolean values.

```cpp
void BiGraph::traverse(int sourceVertex, std::vector<char>& areVisited) const
{
    if (areVisited[sourceVertex])
        return;
    areVisited[sourceVertex] = true;
    for (auto& x:graph[sourceVertex])
    {
        traverse(x, areVisited);
    }
}
```

You are clearly using `areVisited` as a boolean; then the type should be
`std::vector<bool>`.

### Use a single function where possible

```cpp
void BiGraph::traverse(int sourceVertex, std::vector<char>& areVisited) const
{
    if (areVisited[sourceVertex])
        return;
    areVisited[sourceVertex] = true;
    for (auto& x:graph[sourceVertex])
    {
        traverse(x, areVisited);
    }
}

const std::vector<char> BiGraph::areConnectedImpl(int sourceVertex) const
{
    std::vector<char> areVisited(maxVertexCount, false);
    traverse(sourceVertex, areVisited);
    return areVisited;
}
```

`areConnectedImpl` is implemented in terms of `traverse`; maybe you can reconcile
the functions to only have one way to do this.

### Use `std::endl` only if you need a flush

```cpp
void BiGraph::printImpl(std::ostream& os) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
    {
        os << i << ": ";
        for (auto& j:graph[i])
        {
            os << j << ' ';
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`std::endl` will always also call `flush`, which is really slow. If you are
printing lots of elements, consider just using `'\n'` instead.

```cpp
class GraphFactory
{
public:
    GraphFactory()=default;
    ~GraphFactory()=default;
};
```

If your class adheres to the [Rule of Zero](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/01/the-rule-of-zero/),
don't add defaulted constructors and destructors. Although technically `GraphFactory`
does, semantically I think a factory should not be copyable. In that case remove
the copy constructor and assignment operator.

#### If the factory class does nothing, consider using a factory function.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Graph> GraphFactory::getBiGraph(int size, std::string name)
{
    return std::make_unique<BiGraph>(size, name);
}
```

This function does not do much. The calling code could probably just call
`make_unique` on its own. If you really want to hide the `BiGraph` class, you can
provide a simple function, without the factory.

### The inheritance hierarchy does not pull its own weight.

This code looks unnecessarily "object oriented" (in the Java sense). This could
be just one class and everybody, including the compiler, would be happy. C++
is good at creating small code if you let it. There may be good reasons to
do what you did with the factory and implementation hiding, but unless there is
more and a higher goal, this makes no sense.